Is it possible to deploy Milvus on Kubernetes without using Helm?
I'm trying to deploy an application on Kubernetes using a Helm chart, specifically the storage classes, following the instructions provided in the documentation (https://milvus.io/docs/eks.md). However, during the deployment process, I encounter the following error:
cannot create resource "storageclasses" in API group "storage.k8s.io" at the cluster scope

It appears that my team lacks permissions to create cluster-wide resources, such as storage classes. As a result, the Helm deployment fails.
To work around this issue, I'm considering manually provisioning the necessary resources, such as disks, instead of relying on Helm to create them automatically. However, I'm unsure of the exact steps to take in order to achieve this.
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: ebs-gp3-sc
  annotations:
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
provisioner: ebs.csi.aws.com
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
parameters:
  type: gp3
EOF

Could someone please provide guidance on how to manually provision storage resources (e.g., disks) in Kubernetes, and how to integrate them into the Helm deployment?
I am new to kubernetes so any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

It's possible to deploy anything on kubernetes without using Helm. Helm is just a templating tool to generate Kubernetes manifests; you can always create the manifests yourself or using another tool.
